# Showing Edit/Delete links when hover over the data row

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a table with ng-repeat on the `<tr>` at with the last td I have edit/delete links, I only want them to show if user hover over the `<tr>`

```
<tr ng-repeat="form in allData | filter:search | orderBy: orderByValue : orderIn" ng-click="set_index($index)">
          <td><a ng-href={{form.link}}>{{form.ar_ref}}</a></td>
          <td>{{form.title}}</td>
          <td>{{form.category}}
            <span ng-class="{'show_edit_link', $index==selected_index}">
              <button ng-click="showUpdate()">Update</button>
              <button ng-click="showDelete()">Delete</button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

My JS Controller:

```
pp.controller('formsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  $http.get('/php_user/formJSON.php').success(function(response){
    $scope.allData=response; 

    //Show hover edit links
    $scope.selected_index = 0;
    $scope.set_index = function(i){ //i is the $index that we will pass in when hover in the forms_admin.php
      $scope.selected_index = i;
    }
```

CSS:

```
.edit_link_show{
  display: inline;
}
.edit_link{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with reguar css ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONzVLL

Comment: oOo~ nice, clever.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your ng-controller.  It should be a `:` for the expression after class name and you also want to set another ng-class argument for selected_index not equal to $index:

```
<tr ng-repeat="form in allData | filter:search | orderBy: orderByValue : orderIn" ng-click="set_index($index)">
          <td><a ng-href={{form.link}}>{{form.ar_ref}}</a></td>
          <td>{{form.title}}</td>
          <td>{{form.category}}
            <span ng-class="{'show_edit_link': $index==selected_index, 'edit_link': $index!=selected_index}">
              <button ng-click="showUpdate()">Update</button>
              <button ng-click="showDelete()">Delete</button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Good call, a good reminder for this syntax is that ng-class is equal to an object, that should be follow the same structure as the key:value pair like other objects.